# Is there a way to create a DataFrame from specific colour coded rows that are in within a Google Sheet? (gspread and pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, gspread

I have a Google Sheet with large amounts of rows that are colour coded. I was looking to create a new DataFrame based on coloured rows. Is it possible to select rows based on their colour? Or  even if there would is a way select rows that are not color coded.

Can't really find anything on this, so really not sure if this is possible.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `create a new DataFrame based on coloured rows`, `select rows based on their colour` and `select rows that are not color coded`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I have a Google Spreadsheet with number of rows that are colour coded with different colours. I'm looking for a way with pandas and gspread to only extract rows with a specific colour from that sheet into a DataFrame. With this task I'm trying to have a DataFrame created with only red rows in it for example.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that your issue has already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know how to do it with gspread (most likely it’s impossible), but it’s easy with `google-api-python-client` (which is a dependency of gspread)

You need to pass the `includeGridData` parameter to `spreadsheets().get()` method. Here is a slightly modified example from the [doc](http://%20https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get):

```py
data = (
    service.spreadsheets()
    .get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, 
        ranges=ranges, 
        includeGridData=True  # important,
        fields=",".join([  # specify only required fields to reduce response size
            "sheets.data.rowData.values.formattedValue",
            "sheets.data.rowData.values.effectiveFormat.backgroundColor",
        ])
    )
    .execute()
)

# now you should parse returned JSON according your needs, e.g.:

def parse(data): # data type: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet
    white_color = {"red": 1, "green": 1, "blue": 1}

    for grid_data in data["sheets"][0]["data"]:
        # grid_data type: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#GridData
        for row_data in grid_data["rowData"]:
            # row_data["values"] contains a list of cells (CellData), one per column
            # cell_data type: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellData
            row = []
            for cell_data in row_data["values"]:
                value = cell_data["formattedValue"] # or cell_data["userEnteredValue"]
                color = cell_data["effectiveFormat"]["backgroundColor"]
                if color != white_color:
                    row.append(value)
                else:
                    row.append(None)
            yield row

pd.DataFrame(list(parse(data)))
```

Upd: read multiple columns

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very nice API. I'm getting `NameError: name 'row' is not defined` when running this, any ideas?

Comment: @russianmax, sorry, renamed `row` to `grid_data`.

Comment: @russianmax, I also update my answer to iterate multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks man! Exactly what I needed

Comment: Would it be possible to append any column names to the the DataFrame too? I have been trying but can't find a way.

Comment: @russianmax, please, add more context. Do you need to read lines of different lengths? Or add columns after reading? Or rename the columns?

Comment: Sorry nevermind, my bad!

Comment: What's the best way to deal with empty cells? If a cell is empty within a row we get  `KeyError: 'formattedValue'`. If a cell is empty I'd like to leave it that way.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of: `for cell_data in row_data["values"]:      
                if len(row_data["values"]) == 0:
                  value = ''
                else:
                  value = cell_data["formattedValue"]`

Comment: If you have empty cells, you can use `cell_data.get("formattedValue", <default>)`, because `cell_data` is a dict. If you have lines of different lengths, you can pre-initialize `row` (`row = [None] * n_columns )` and set values via `row[i] = cell_data.get("formattedValue")`

Comment: What should go in the default field within the `.get`? Should be `''` right?

Comment: First I added in `value = cell_data.get("formattedValue",'')` as you said, and then had to add `if value == '':` `value = ''`

Comment: > What should go in the default field within the `.get`. I don't know. It depends on your data and business logic.

Answer (score 0):

I had to slight modify your answer to get past `NameError: name 'row' is not defined`

```
data = (
    service.spreadsheets()
    .get(
        spreadsheetId=sheet_id,
        ranges=ranges,
        includeGridData=True,  # important,
        fields=",".join([  # specify only required fields to reduce response size
            "sheets.data.rowData.values.formattedValue",
            #"sheets.data.rowData.values.effectiveFormat.textFormat.strikethrough",
            "sheets.data.rowData.values.effectiveFormat.backgroundColor",
        ])
    )
    .execute()
)

def parse(data):
    white_color = {"red": 1, "green": 1, "blue": 1}
    for grid_data in data["sheets"][0]["data"]:
      for row_data in grid_data["rowData"]:
        cell_data = row_data["values"][0]
        value = cell_data["formattedValue"]
        color = cell_data["effectiveFormat"]["backgroundColor"]
        if color == white_color:
          yield value

print(pd.DataFrame({"column": list(parse(data))}))
```

This is nearly what I need. In this solution only first column is returned, how do you iterate remaining columns?